# how to make information displayed only in child window?

Tags: javascript, jsp

i hav written code for opening the child window(toolbar is disabled here) thro parent window by( using body onload function) calling the same(login.jsp) page again.

wen the parent window (i.e login.jsp) opens for the first time in the browser(by typing the url) it displays all the information and then goes to child window where i have disabled the toolbar.

wat i want is wen i type the url and click go i dont want any information to be displayed in parent window... i want to display only in the child window.

could anyone please come up with an idea or little bit of code to do this??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but after your script has done everything in the child window, and has tried `focus()` ing it, you should be able to just point the parent's location to `about:blank`:

```
location.href = 'about:blank';
```

of course, pointing it to an empty page within your site would do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a blank start page that opens a new window with the login page displayed.